# Elastic Search custom logger for Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging

Currently we have several Java micro service apps that use Elastic Search, and for debugging purposes we have the logging set to tracer. This outputs all ES requests and responses to the logs. We really only need requests, and only on non-production. For all environments we want to keep search response times along with a custom header that we set for tracking purposes across multiple micro service apps.

I see that in .NET there is a custom solution that would work perfectly for us: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html#logging-with-on-request-completed but sadly I can't seem to find a matching Java feature.

Is there a way to do this using Java?

Answer (score 0):

If I got you question correct then you want the following :-

1. Log every elasticsearch query only (and not response) from different
   microservices.
2. You just want it on your test clusters

There is a workaround in elastisearch for the same. Elasticsearch itself logs the queries made to it and you just need to set a threshold for it. So any query that takes more time than that threshold would be logged in a separate file "*_slow_log.*" in your logs folder. You just simply need to set the threshold to "0" to log every query only and agin this can be done in testing enviorments for your particular usecase.

There are a lot of configuration options in it and would recommend you to check this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html